# textureview is not updating after coming back from another activity in onResume

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, textureview

I am trying to play some rtsp video on custom textureview.Video is playing for the first time but when I go to second activity where the same video is played (not reinstantiated,same session but with different textureview) there it is playing and coming back to first activity where I am setting the sureface again in onResume textureview is still showing the content where it was left for the first time.Interesting fact is like video is still playing, just it is not visible in the textureview and if I go to second screen like before it is showing.I tried both releasing the surfacetexture and not releasing, tried also releasing the surface which I am holding a reference in the first activity for future use, not any of those seems to work.What can be the possible reason?

in onResume I am checking if app is coming back from app drawer or full screen activity.Where making the app go to background by clicking home button and coming back to app from app drawer video is playing.Only when coming back from full screen it's not working.

StreamingActivity.java

```
package com.wiznsystems.android.activities;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.myeglu.android.R;
import com.myeglu.zoomview.ZoomTextureView;
import com.wiznsystems.android.App;
import com.wiznsystems.android.data.objects.FFMPEG;
import com.wiznsystems.android.utils.Constants;
import com.wiznsystems.android.utils.Events;
import com.wiznsystems.android.utils.FFMPEGPlayer;

import java.io.File;

import de.greenrobot.event.EventBus;
import hugo.weaving.DebugLog;
import timber.log.Timber;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")
public class StreamingActivity extends Fragment implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener{

    private static boolean loadedLibraries;
    private boolean comingFromAppDrawer;
    private boolean isComingFromFullScreen;
    boolean anotherVideo=false;
    boolean shouldTextureUpdate=false;
    Surface surface;
    public StreamingActivity(){

    }


    public static ZoomTextureView surfaceView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    public static boolean isPlaying;
    private int isInitialized;
    public static int isFullScreenDisplayed=0;
    private String url;
    public boolean isFirstTime;
    private FFMPEG ffmpeg;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private final String TAG=StreamingActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    int w=0,h=0;
    private boolean isFirstTimeForFullscreen=true;
    private Button fullScreenButton;
    FFMPEGPlayer ffmpegPlayer;
    String buttonText="";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        url=getArguments().getString("url");
        Log.d("ANURAN",url);
        //getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
        ffmpegPlayer=App.getFFMPEG();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_streaming,null,false);
        surfaceView = (ZoomTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        frameLayout=(FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.streaming_framelayout);
        progressBar = ((ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar));
        fullScreenButton=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.fullScreenButton);

        fullScreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    isFullScreenDisplayed = 1;
                    isComingFromFullScreen = true;
                    shouldTextureUpdate=true;
                    if (isFirstTimeForFullscreen) {
                        //ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(null);
                        isFirstTimeForFullscreen = false;
                    }
                    //surfaceView.getSurfaceTexture().release();
                    //surface.release();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    goFullScreen();

                } catch (Exception throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d("ANURAN","onCreateView called");

        surfaceView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);




        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //Log.d(TAG,url);
    }



    @DebugLog
    private void postInit() {

        Events.PlayButtonBGChanger playButtonBGChanger=new Events.PlayButtonBGChanger();

        if (isInitialized==0) {
            playButtonBGChanger.setShouldChange(true);
            initPlay();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if(isInitialized==-999){

            playButtonBGChanger.setShouldChange(false);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Snackbar.make(frameLayout,"Please make sure you have stopped other playing videos before playing this one.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {

            playButtonBGChanger.setShouldChange(false);
            Snackbar.make(frameLayout,"Something went wrong while live streaming.Please try again later.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        EventBus.getDefault().post(playButtonBGChanger);
    }

    private void initPlay() {
        try {
            int[] res = ffmpegPlayer.libGetVideoRes();
            Log.d("ANURAN", "res width " + res[0] + ": height " + res[1]);
            if (res[0] <= 0) {
                res[0] = 480;
            }
            if (res[1] <= 0) {
                res[1] = 320;
            }
            int[] screenRes = getScreenRes();
            int width, height;
            float widthScaledRatio = screenRes[0] * 1.0f / res[0];
            float heightScaledRatio = screenRes[1] * 1.0f / res[1];
            if (widthScaledRatio > heightScaledRatio) {
                //use heightScaledRatio
                width = (int) (res[0] * heightScaledRatio);
                height = screenRes[1];
            } else {
                //use widthScaledRatio
                width = screenRes[0];
                height = (int) (res[1] * widthScaledRatio);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "width " + width + ",height:" + height);
            w=width;
            h=height;
            updateSurfaceView(width, height);
            try{
                ffmpegPlayer.libSetup(width,height);
                if(this.surface == null){
                    Log.d("ANURAN","surface is null");
                }
                if(anotherVideo)
                    ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(null);
                ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(surface);
                Log.d("ANURAN","libsetsurface set initPlay()");
            }catch (Exception throwable){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Something went wrong while live streaming.Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            playMedia();
        }catch (Exception throwable){
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public FFMPEGPlayer getFFMPEGPlayer(){
        return this.ffmpegPlayer;
    }

    private void playMedia() {
        if(progressBar.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        try{
            ffmpegPlayer.libPlay();

        }catch (Exception throwable){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Something went wrong while live streaming.Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        isPlaying = true;
        CamerasActivity.isPlaying=true;
    }

    @DebugLog
    private void updateSurfaceView(int pWidth, int pHeight) {
        //update surfaceview dimension, this will cause the native window to change
        Log.d("ANURAN UPDATE SURFACE", "width " + pWidth + ",height:" + pHeight);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = pWidth;
        params.height = pHeight;
        surfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);
        surfaceView.requestLayout();
    }

    @DebugLog
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private int[] getScreenRes() {
        int[] res = new int[2];
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        res[0] = size.x;
        res[1] = size.y;
        return res;
    }


    public void stopPlaying() {
        isPlaying = false;
        try{

            ffmpegPlayer.libStop();
//            ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(null);
//            surfaceView.getSurfaceTexture().release();
//            surfaceView.getSurfaceTexture().detachFromGLContext();

        }catch (Exception throwable){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
//        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onStop called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        stopPlaying();
        comingFromAppDrawer=true;
//        if(surfaceView.getSurfaceTexture() !=null){
//            surfaceView.getSurfaceTexture().release();
//
//        }
//        if(surface !=null){
//            surface.release();
//            surface=null;
//        }


//        if(isFullScreenDisplayed==0){
//            stopPlaying();
//        }
        Log.d("ANURAN onStop",surface.isValid()+"");
        super.onStop();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
//        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onStop called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        stopPlaying();
        isComingFromFullScreen=true;
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(isComingFromFullScreen){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if(surface !=null){
                ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(null);
                Log.d("ANURAN onResume","value of surface "+surface.isValid());
                ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(surface);

            }
        }
        else if(comingFromAppDrawer){
            //stopPlaying();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if(surface !=null){
                ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(null);
                //ffmpegPlayer.libSetup(w,h);
                ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(surface);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        if(this.surface !=null) {
            this.surface.release();
            this.surface=null;
        }
        this.surface=new Surface(surface);
        Log.d("ANURAN","surfacetexture available streaming activity");
        new PlayVideo().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        Log.d("ANURAN","surfacetexturesize changed streaming activity");
        try{
            w=width;
            h=height;
            this.surface.release();
            this.surface=null;
            this.surface=new Surface(surface);
            if(isComingFromFullScreen){
                //surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface().release();
                updateSurfaceView(width, height);
                ffmpegPlayer.libSetup(width,height);
                ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(this.surface);
            }

        }catch (Exception throwable){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Something went wrong while live streaming.Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        Log.d("ANURAN","surfacetexture destroyed streaming activity");
//        surfaceView.getSurfaceTexture().release();
//        if(this.surface !=null){
//            this.surface.release();
//            this.surface=null;
//        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        Log.d("ANURAN","surfacetexture updated streaming activity");
        if(this.surface !=null){
            this.surface.release();
            this.surface=null;
            this.surface=new Surface(surface);
        }else{
            this.surface=new Surface(surface);
        }

    }


    public class PlayVideo extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try{

                isInitialized=ffmpegPlayer.libInit(url);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Snackbar.make(frameLayout,"Exception Occured",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            isFirstTime=false;
            postInit();
            this.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    public void onEvent(FFMPEG ffmpeg){

        url = ffmpeg.getUrl();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //stopPlaying();
        anotherVideo=true;
        new PlayVideo().execute();
    }

    public void onEvent(Events.UpdateUrl newurl){
        url=newurl.getUrl();
    }

    public void onEvent(Events.StopPlayback event){
        stopPlaying();
    }

    public void onEvent(Events.NotifyPlayer notifyPlayer){
        Snackbar.make(frameLayout,"Please stop any running video before playing another one",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void goFullScreen(){

        Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),FullScreenActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url",url);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }



}
```

FullScreenActivity.java

```
package com.wiznsystems.android.activities;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.myeglu.android.R;
import com.myeglu.zoomview.AngleView;
import com.myeglu.zoomview.MatrixChangeListener;
import com.myeglu.zoomview.ZoomTextureView;
import com.wiznsystems.android.App;
import com.wiznsystems.android.data.objects.FFMPEG;
import com.wiznsystems.android.utils.FFMPEGPlayer;

import uk.copywitchshame.senab.photoview.gestures.PhotoViewAttacher;
import hugo.weaving.DebugLog;

/**
 * Created by anuran on 9/3/18.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")
public class FullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, PhotoViewAttacher.OnMatrixChangedListener {

    private ZoomTextureView surfaceView;
    public static AngleView  angleView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private PhotoViewAttacher photoViewAttacher;
    public static boolean isPlaying;
    private boolean isInitialized;
    private String url;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    Surface surface;
    private final String TAG=StreamingActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public int backCounter=0;
    FFMPEGPlayer ffmpegPlayer;
    boolean fromADorSL=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        surfaceView = (ZoomTextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        angleView=(AngleView)findViewById(R.id.render_angle_view);
        surfaceView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
        frameLayout=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.streaming_framelayout);
        progressBar = ((ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar));
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        url=getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        //new PlayVideo().execute();
        ffmpegPlayer= App.getFFMPEG();
        Log.d("ANURAN","fullscreen onCreate");

    }
//    @DebugLog
//    private void postInit() {
//        if (isInitialized) {
//            initPlay();
//            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//        } else {
//            finish();
//        }
//    }



//    private void initPlay() {
//
//        try{
//            int[] res = FFMPEGPlayer.libGetVideoRes();
//            Log.d("ANURAN", "res width " + res[0] + ": height " + res[1]);
//            if (res[0] <= 0) {
//                res[0] = 480;
//            }
//            if (res[1] <= 0) {
//                res[1] = 320;
//            }
//            int[] screenRes = getScreenRes();
//            int width, height;
//            float widthScaledRatio = screenRes[0] * 1.0f / res[0];
//            float heightScaledRatio = screenRes[1] * 1.0f / res[1];
//            if (widthScaledRatio > heightScaledRatio) {
//                //use heightScaledRatio
//                width = (int) (res[0] * heightScaledRatio);
//                height = screenRes[1];
//            } else {
//                //use widthScaledRatio
//                width = screenRes[0];
//                height = (int) (res[1] * widthScaledRatio);
//            }
//            Log.d(TAG, "width " + width + ",height:" + height);
//            updateSurfaceView(width, height);
//            FFMPEGPlayer.libSetup(width, height);
//            playMedia();
//
//            photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(surfaceView, width, height);
//            photoViewAttacher.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
//            photoViewAttacher.setOnMatrixChangeListener(this);
//            photoViewAttacher.update();
//        }catch (Exception e){
//
//        }
//    }

//    private void playMedia() {
//
//        try{
//            if(progressBar.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
//                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            }
//            FFMPEGPlayer.libPlay();
//            isPlaying = true;
//            CamerasActivity.isPlaying=true;
//        }catch (Exception e){
//
//        }
//    }

//    @DebugLog
//    private void updateSurfaceView(int pWidth, int pHeight) {
//        //update surfaceview dimension, this will cause the native window to change
//        Log.d("ANURAN UPDATE SURFACE", "width " + pWidth + ",height:" + pHeight);
//        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
//        params.width = pWidth;
//        params.height = pHeight;
//        surfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);
//    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(backCounter==1){
            super.onBackPressed();
        }else{
            //surface.release();
            StreamingActivity.isFullScreenDisplayed=0;

            surfaceView.getSurfaceTexture().release();
            //ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(null);
            if(this.surface !=null){
                this.surface.release();
                this.surface=null;
            }
            backCounter++;
            Toast.makeText(FullScreenActivity.this,"Press back again to quit full screen",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    @DebugLog
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private int[] getScreenRes() {
        int[] res = new int[2];
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        res[0] = size.x;
        res[1] = size.y;
        return res;
    }


    private void stopPlaying() {
        isPlaying = false;
        try{
            ffmpegPlayer.libStop();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        fromADorSL=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(fromADorSL){
            ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(null);
            ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(this.surface);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }



    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        //Toast.makeText(FullScreenActivity.this,"SurfaceTexture available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //updateSurfaceView(width, height);
        try{
            this.surface=new Surface(surface);
            ffmpegPlayer.libSetup(width, height);
            ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(this.surface);
            photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(surfaceView, width, height);
            photoViewAttacher.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            photoViewAttacher.setOnMatrixChangeListener(this);
            photoViewAttacher.update();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            angleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        try{
            Toast.makeText(FullScreenActivity.this,"SurfaceTexture changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (photoViewAttacher != null ) {
                photoViewAttacher.update ();
            }
            if(this.surface !=null){
                this.surface.release();
            }
            this.surface=null;
            this.surface=new Surface(surface);
            ffmpegPlayer.libSetup(width,height);
            ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(this.surface);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        try{
//            this.surface.release();
//            this.surface=null;
            surfaceView.getSurfaceTexture().release();
            if(this.surface !=null){
                this.surface.release();
                this.surface=null;
            }
            //ffmpegPlayer.libSetSurface(null);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        if(this.surface !=null){
            this.surface.release();
            this.surface=null;
            this.surface=new Surface(surface);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMatrixChanged(Matrix matrix, RectF rectF) {
        float maxMovement = (rectF.width() - surfaceView.getWidth());
        float middle = surfaceView.getWidth() * 0.5f + surfaceView.getLeft();
        float currentMiddle = rectF.width() * 0.5f + rectF.left;
        float angle=(-(int) ((currentMiddle - middle) * 100 / maxMovement));

        Log.d("ANURAN",angle+"");
        angleView.setCurrentProgress((int)angle);
    }



//    public class PlayVideo extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
//
//        @Override
//        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
//            try{
//                isInitialized=(FFMPEGPlayer.libInit(url)==0);
//            }catch (Exception e){
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
//            return null;
//        }
//
//        @Override
//        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
//            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
//            postInit();
//            this.cancel(true);
//        }
//    }


}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past. Do you see this on Android version 7.0 and higher? Is the same problem occurs on Android 6.0 for instance?